# How to delete records that match a condition and leave one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure where I want to delete all records but one that match a certain condition. I can't seem to figure it out.

I have the following temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_RESULTS(
    code NVARCHAR(50),
    newCode NVARCHAR(50),
    result NVARCHAR(10)
)
```

Then I have code that inserts data in that table. Basically, the records look like that:

```
code  newCode   result
A1      B1       <15
A1      B2       <20
A1      B3       <30 -- in this case one of the three A1s should stay in the table
A2      B4        25 -- this is staying
A2      B5       <45
A3      B6       <22
```

After that, I am trying to:

```
DELETE TR
FROM #TEMP_RESULTS TR
WHERE   TR.result LIKE '<%' -- here I need to add another condition that can leave one row in the table
```

**EDIT**: Forgot to mention, that searched on the Internet, but most of the topics were about removing duplicates or selecting TOP records.

**EDIT2**: This is the desired output:

```
code  newCode   result
A1      B1       <15
A2      B4        25 -- this is staying
A2      B5       <45
A3      B6       <22
```

This is done, because later I would like to update the result to something else. There is no constraint and no grouping.

Comment: Is there any constraint on which of the rows is staying?  E.g. the one with the greatest value for newCode?  Also, it vaguely sounds like you means this to be grouped somehow.  E.g. the A3 row should stay since it's the only A3 row.  Can you provide what your desired output would be for your example?

Comment: @DerekElkins There is no constraint and no grouping. I've update the question with the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `CTE` with a `WHERE` clause:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM #TEMP_RESULTS  
    WHERE result LIKE '<%'
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE rn > 1
```

Modify the `ORDER BY` depending on which row you want to stay.

Comment: Thank you, Felix! I am testing at the moment, seems to work fine, but for some reason it always leaves a row where the result is `<%'. I can fix that with an extra delete statement.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you provide more data showing what you said?